# button on a map is not getting displayed?

Tags: ios, google-maps, uibutton

In my app, I have a map view, I want to display a custom button on the map, if a place the button, it gets displayed but, if I place a background image for the image, it is not getting printed.

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
@"Button_Default.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: 
@"Button_Highlighted.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 100, 200, 40)];
[self.view addSubview:customButton];
```

I have also tried changing the last line as

```
[mapView addSubview:customButton];
```

Comment: can you replace "[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: 
@"Button_Highlighted.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];" with "[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: 
@"Button_Highlighted.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];" and please let me know.. if its working or not

Comment: Make sure that you have the assets in your resource folder like "Button_Default.png" & "Button_Highlighted.png"

Comment: I am sure I am using .png files

Comment: Actually if I click the specifed location, the action is done, the only problem is the imaged button is not getting displayed.

Comment: @nikhilgohil11, is it that U want me to try using different images, right?

Comment: Ya, now it is getting displayed. Thanks @nikhilgohil11

Comment: I just used a smaller image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that you have the images added to your project, may be in resource folder & the file name you are using in your code should not be misspelled (quiet often people do typo mistakes like using keyword `imagedNamed` instead of `imageNamed`).